# PDO login script won't work

Tags: pdo

I changed this login script to PDO. Now it passes the username but get's stuck fetchAll line. I need help please. thanks

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once"includes/config.php";

if (isset($_POST['admin_login'])) {
  $admin_user = trim($_POST['admin_user']);
  $admin_pw = trim($_POST['admin_pw']);

  if ($admin_user == NULL OR $admin_pw == NULL) {
    $final_report.="Please complete all the fields below..";
  } else {
    $check_user_data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin` 
      WHERE `admin_user`='$admin_user'");
    $check_user_data->execute();

    if ($check_user_data->fetchColumn() == 0) {
      $final_report.="This admin username does not exist..";
    } else {
      $get_user_data = $check_user_data->fetchAll($check_user_data);

      if ($get_user_data['admin_pw'] == $admin_pw) {
        $start_idsess = $_SESSION['admin_user'] = "".$get_user_data['admin_user']."";
        $start_passsess = $_SESSION['admin_pw'] = "".$get_user_data['admin_pw']."";
        $final_report.="You are about to be logged in, please wait a few moments...";
        header('Location: admin.php');
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Not checking return value prepare() or execute() for `false`.  You need to check for SQL errors and handle them, stopping the code instead of continuing on blithely.
- Not using query parameters in the prepared statement, still interpolating $_POST content into the query unsafely.  You're missing the benefit of switching to PDO, and leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attack.
- You're storing passwords in plaintext, which is unsafe.  See [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).
- Do you really need to `SELECT *` if you only use the admin_pw column?  Hint: no.
- [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array of arrays, not just one array for a row.  Read the examples in the documentation for fetchAll().

Comment: I'm new in PDO, how I should change it that it would work. Thanks

Comment: @user1858570 It might help to read a few tutorials to get you up to speed with the benefits of PDO. Off the top of my head (well, favorites list, but anyway) I can recommend http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: thanks, it looks really helpful article, but I'm not sure if I can get my script changed the way I need it.

Comment: @user1858570, I also recommend http://phpsecurity.org/ and Chris Shiflett's book Essential PHP Security.  Like an electrician is responsible for knowing how to avoid fire hazards, you are responsible for security hazards if you put your code on the internet.